# Cannot locate node of type [stereo_vslam_node] in package [vslam_system]

Tags: ros, vslam-system

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run VSLAM on Stereo Data. When trying to roslaunch stereo_vslam.launch, I'm getting this error message cannot launch node of type [vslam_system/stereo_vslam_node]: Cannot locate node of type [stereo_vslam_node] in package [vslam_system].  I cheched and found stereo_vslam_node was under vslam/bin, ans was not sure why ROS could not locate it?

I found a similar question posted earlier, and followed suggestions described in the "answer" section, but still got the same error message.  Any advices will be appreciated.

Thanks
CC

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11053/cannot-locate-node-of-type-%5Bstereo_vslam_node%5D-in-package-%5Bvslam_system%5D/) by [CC](https://answers.ros.org/users/1009/cc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-08-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

vslam is experimental research code. It is not actively being supported, but patches are welcome.

If you would like a robust method of localization and mapping with a stereo camera or kinect, use the 2D slam_gmapping stack. See the pointcloud_to_laserscan package from the turtlebot stack and the SLAM Gmapping with Kinect Tutorial for the turtlebot.

---

Originally posted by [Helen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1033/helen/) with karma: 261 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0